# How to use Voximplant to do voice calling in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, voximplant

I am trying to implement voximplant for voice calls into a chat rn app, Can anyone please help me do implement a simple version of it? I saw the Voximplant rn demo repos but I couldn't find a very simple straight forward example for voice calls,

however, currently, I created 3 screen Login, Calling, and IncomingCalling in the login screen I implemented a simple login function that login users I created in my Voixmplant control panel, and I can now login into one user that I created and navigate to call screen,

Can anyone please help me how to make a real voice call within the app? like I don't want to create a separate screen for user address book/contacts but instead, I directly want to call a user with username "testuser2" when any user logged in How can I implement this?
The calling screen and incoming calling screen is a very simple UI it just have a few buttons

Login:

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    async function login() {
        try {
            let clientState = await voximplant.getClientState();
            if (clientState === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
                await voximplant.connect();
                await voximplant.login(
                    `${user}@${VOXIMPLANT_APP}.${VOXIMPLANT_ACCOUNT}.voximplant.com`,
                    password,
                );
            }
            if (clientState === Voximplant.ClientState.CONNECTED) {
                await voximplant.login(
                    `${user}@${VOXIMPLANT_APP}.${VOXIMPLANT_ACCOUNT}.voximplant.com`,
                    password,
                );
            }
            navigation.navigate('callscreen');
        } catch (e) {
            let message;
            switch (e.name) {
                case Voximplant.ClientEvents.ConnectionFailed:
                    message = 'Connection error, check your internet connection';
                    break;
                case Voximplant.ClientEvents.AuthResult:
                    message = convertCodeMessage(e.code);
                    break;
                default:
                    message = 'Unknown error. Try again';
            }
            showLoginError(message);
        }
    }

    function convertCodeMessage(code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 401:
                return 'Invalid password';
            case 404:
                return 'Invalid user';
            case 491:
                return 'Invalid state';
            default:
                return 'Try again later';
        }
    }

    function showLoginError(message) {
        Alert.alert('Login error', message, [
            {
                text: 'OK',
            },
        ]);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.safearea}>
                <View style={[styles.container]}>
                    <TextInput
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        style={styles.forminput}
                        placeholder="User name"
                        autoFocus={true}
                        returnKeyType={'next'}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        blurOnSubmit={false}
                        onChangeText={(text) => setUser(text)}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        style={styles.forminput}
                        placeholder="User password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                        blurOnSubmit={true}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => login()} style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.textButton}>LOGIN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set up your Voximplant application in the Voximplant Control Panel

- you need [a VoxEngine scenario](https://voximplant.com/docs/gettingstarted/basicconcepts/scenarios)
  example:

```
VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, (e) => {
  const newCall = VoxEngine.callUserDirect(
    e.call,
    e.destination,
    {
      displayName: e.displayName,
      callerid: e.callerid,
      headers: e.headers,
    }
  );
  VoxEngine.easyProcess(e.call, newCall, ()=>{}, true);
});
```

- and [a routing rule](https://voximplant.com/docs/gettingstarted/basicconcepts/routing). I recommend to use the pattern `.*` that means any quantity of any symbols, so all the usernames match the rule.

I assume you have 2 Voximplant users that can login in the application, let say "testuser1" and "testuser2"

To make a voice call from "testuser1" to "testuser2", you need to use Client.call API.

example:

```
const client = Voximplant.getInstance();
let callSettings = {
  video: {
    sendVideo: false,
    receiveVideo: false,
  },
};
let call = await client.call("testuser2", callSettings);
```

If the Voximplant application in the Voximplant Control Panel is set up correctly, "testuser2" should receive an incoming call via [IncomingCall event](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/clienteventtypes#incomingcall).

Then, it is required to subscribe to call events to get notified when the call is connected/disconnected/failed.

Please take a look at [the sample code](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo/blob/4267a41504aa03d9473190a4dd38fdc534687d7f/CallApp/src/CallScreen.js)

Comment: Thank you very much Yulia for answering How to check that is my voice and other user voice coming not?

Comment: I can use the following events:
- CallEvents.ICECompleted - means the audio should be bidirectional
- QualityEvents.noAudioReceive - indicates there is a network issue during a call on other user side
- CallEvents.CallReconnecting / CallEvents.CallReconnected - if there is a network issue on the current user side / the issue is gone